# xunit testing web api core file uploading method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

It is ASP.NET Web API Core 2.1 and method fileupload. I am using
the `Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();`
method to get the file form client.

Now I want to write a test method with xunit framework.
How can I do it? I want to upload file form test method and get in web api controller. I have tried, see code below. I could not get file in Web API.

```cs
public class DocumentControllerTest
{
        [Fact]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            DocumentController documentController = new DocumentController();

            documentController.ControllerContext = RequestWithFile();
           
            var result = documentController.Upload();
        }


        private ControllerContext RequestWithFile()
        {
            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
            httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form data");
            
            var file = new FormFile(new 
              MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a dummy file")), 0, 0, "Data", "dummy.txt");

            httpContext.Request.Form = new FormCollection(new 
              Dictionary<string, StringValues>(), new FormFileCollection { file });

         var actx = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new 
         ControllerActionDescriptor());
         return new ControllerContext(actx);
       }
}
```